# Get_post_meta Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Need help with a wordpress get_meta_post. 
I need to display a div only if the custom-field promo is found in the get_meta_post. If true this is suppose to echo the :

```
<?php get_post_meta(get_the_ID('promo', true)  
<div class="packagePromoItem">Promotion</div>
?>
```

Comment: Did you just throw this code example up so no one would ask to show your attempt or is this your actual attempt? I only ask because I don't know that one could call this an attempt...missing bracket, mixing html with php...Is this a lazy code sample, or have you never used php before? I could excuse this if you have never used php before...

Comment: I never use php sorry, I try to convert something done with the toolset pluggin to php.

Comment: But today I learn that the get_post_meta can tell me if the custom-field I target here is in the loop with a return of true or false.

Answer (score 1):

You're using get_the_ID wrong. Get the ID does not accept any parameters and gets the ID of the current post. If you need to check if the post has meta 'promo', then just check if get_post_meta returns null/false.

I'm not sure what you're asking through your example though. If you're trying to echo out the post meta:

```
<?php if (get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'promo', true))) { echo'<div          
class="packagePromoItem">' . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'promo', true) .   
'</div>';}?>
```

Comment: Something like that:
    <?php if( get_post_meta("promo", true) ): ?>
    <?php echo <div class="packagePromoItem">Promotion</div>
    <?php else : ?>

<?php endif; ?>

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that's your actual code, you have several typos, or major misunderstandings about how PHP works.  This should work (using alternative syntax, which I think is a little more readable for this):

```
<?php $promo = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'promo', true); ?>

<?php if ($promo): ?>
  <div class="packagePromoItem">Promotion</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I've also assigned the `promo` post meta to its own variable so it's easier to follow.